# DocuSign Envelope Creation REST API Suddenly Started Failing Wilh: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: docusignapi

Till couple of weeks back following Payload was working fine without any issues when used for Creating Envelope:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <emailSubject>Sign Contract Purchase Agreement 1002601.
  </emailSubject>
  <emailBlurb>
  </emailBlurb>
  <status>created</status>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <documentId>1</documentId>
      <name>PA_204_1002601_0.pdf</name>
    </document>
  </documents>
  <recipients>
    <signers>
      <signer>
        <recipientId>1</recipientId>
        <name>CVBUYER15</name>
        <email>xyz.pqr@abc.com</email>
        <tabs>
          <signHereTabs>
            <signHere>
              <anchorString>sign_internal_2</anchorString>
              <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
              <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
              <anchorUnits>Inches</anchorUnits>
              <xPosition>null</xPosition>
              <yPosition>null</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>null</pageNumber>
            </signHere>
          </signHereTabs>
          <fullNameTabs>
            <fullName>
              <anchorString>name_internal_2</anchorString>
              <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
              <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
              <anchorUnits>Inches</anchorUnits>
              <xPosition>null</xPosition>
              <yPosition>null</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>null</pageNumber>
            </fullName>
          </fullNameTabs>
          <titleTabs>
            <title>
              <anchorString>title_internal_2</anchorString>
              <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
              <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
              <anchorUnits>Inches</anchorUnits>
              <xPosition>null</xPosition>
              <yPosition>null</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>null</pageNumber>
            </title>
          </titleTabs>
          <dateSignedTabs>
            <dateSigned>
              <anchorString>sign_date_internal_2</anchorString>
              <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
              <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
              <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
              <anchorUnits>Inches</anchorUnits>
              <xPosition>null</xPosition>
              <yPosition>null</yPosition>
              <documentId>1</documentId>
              <pageNumber>null</pageNumber>
            </dateSigned>
          </dateSignedTabs>
        </tabs>
      </signer>
    </signers>
  </recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

But it suddenly stopped working in last week. When we remove Tabs tag from above payload the API call goes through fine.

We need to understand why has the payload which was working for fine for more than one year has stopped working suddenly???

Thanks,
Yogesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the problem on the demo.docusign.net platform (the developer sandbox?)

I suggest doing stepwise refinement to isolate the problem until you find the specific issue within the tabs tag.

I'd start by removing the extraneous tags with value `null`. Or replace `null` with false / 0 or whatever you think best.

**Added**

My thanks to the original poster who did some further investigation. He found that when any of the following parameters is set to `null`, the API call fails:

- xPosition
- yPosition
- pageNumber

Looking at the documentation for the parameters in the `approve` object on the [Envelopes: create](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definitions) page, we see that none of the parameters is documented to work with a `null` value.

Therefore, while the breaking change is unfortunate, it will not be reversed. Reason: "As designed."

Comment: Why is there a sudden change in behavior of the API? Same Payload worked fine till last week of February...

Comment: I am sorry that a change affected you, it was not planned. We never plan breaking changes. The API implementation is updated every month. The goal is zero breaking changes for existing implementations. DocuSign runs thousands of regression tests to ensure this is the case. But there's the possibility that something can slip through the cracks. If you're able to exactly identify what changed, then I will file an internal bug report on the issue.  Regards, Larry Kluger, DocuSign

Comment: Thanks Larry. We will try to figure out what is broken.

Comment: Hi Larry,

Issue is reproducible when any of the following 3 elements is null:

<xPosition></xPosition>
<yPosition></yPosition>
<pageNumber></pageNumber>

Please let us know by when the issue will be resolved.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @YogeshMahajan, I have updated my answer, please see above.

Comment: Hi Larry, Thanks for your help. One last question, we are removing complete tabs section itself from the payload, as we don't need to add any automatic signatory/participant. This change is working fine, do you anticipate any issues in future with this change we are doing?

Comment: Sorry @YogeshMahajan, I don't understand your question. **Please post it as a new question on stackoverflow.** Are you correcting an envelope that is in flight? Are you changing a draft envelope? Which api calls are you using? Thanks.